# Coffee doesn't show up in "Your Communities" dropdown

Tags: bug

I've "joined" the Coffee site.  If I'm on another StackExchange site, I can click on the dropdown on the upper left corner and there's a list very close to the top of "Your Communities" that shows all the StackExchange sites I regularly read... except the Coffee site.

If I want to check out Coffee, I have to scroll through the full list.  C is fairly early in the alphabet, but it still bothers me to have to do this scrolling to visit the site.

I'm a lurker (I don't have knowledge to provide answers, and all my questions so far are already covered) - would that be part of the problem?

Is this a bug or intended?  Is there anything I can do to add Coffee to my "Your Communities" list?

Comment: Also, by default, your top five communities (by rep) are shown

Comment: @PythonMaster Ah ha!  Coffee was the sixth community I joined, that explains why it didn't get default added like the previous five.  Thank you, it is a good feeling to understand why this happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Coffee -- lurkers are welcome! :)

I'm not sure if (or by what metrics) the Stack Exchange menu auto-populates, but the menu *is* customizable/editable.

Select the menu; under "YOUR COMMUNITIES" section, select blue "edit" link. You should be able to type in "coffee" in the "search", select the site, and click the "Add" button. You can also re-order the list in the "edit" view by dragging-dropping the entries up or down in the list. The full instructions are on [this entry at the SE blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/03/your-communities-list-is-now-customizable/).

Comment: Aaaah, so easy and I completely missed that.  Maybe the auto-populate for the other communities depleted my brain cell reserve?  In any case, thank you!